# How does an object without an owner know when to drop?

Tags: rust

Seemingly a simple question.

If we define a string and take a reference to it immediately. Since it doesn't have an owner, how does it know when to drop?

```
{
    let not_an_owner: &String = &String::from("Hello There");
}
```

Does the object know about its scope? I thought all variables had to have an owner for them to know when it goes out of scope to trigger the drop.

Comment: rust is just creating a temporary variable for you

Comment: That’s actually `let not_an_owner = String::from("Hello There"); let not_an_owner: &String = &not_an_owner;`. General Kenobi btw.